# linked list printing

Tags: c, list, linked-list

im making this linked (code above) and i need that when the information (country) is the same as the previous information the linked list update only the count and the information is not stored example

if there is this input

```
mmm 1
mmm 2
mmm 3
```

output will need to be `mmm3`

what should i do to make this happen

```
void insertitem(ListNode **startPtr,booking_type* bookings){
    int ans=0;

    ListNode *prevNode =NULL ,*curNode=*startPtr;

    ListNode *newNode = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    strcpy(newNode->data, bookings->country); //newNode->data =bookings->country;
    newNode->nextPtr = NULL;
    newNode->count = 1;  
    while ((curNode!=NULL)&&(strcmp(curNode->data,bookings->country)<=0) ) // future : use strcmp 
    {
      if(strcmp(curNode->data,bookings->country)==0){
        newNode->count++;
      }

      prevNode=curNode;
      curNode = prevNode->nextPtr;
    }

    if(prevNode == NULL)
        *startPtr=newNode;
    else
        prevNode->nextPtr = newNode;

    newNode->nextPtr = curNode;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to explain what you want a little better; it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: What is the wrong output you get?

Comment: in other words i need that when the information of country is the same as the previous one stored in the linked list only the count will be updated.

Comment: if the input is `aaa, bbb, aaa, ccc, ddd, ddd`, then what should be the output?

Comment: aaa 2, bbb 1, ccc1, ddd2

Comment: I rolled back to the previous revision. Deleting the entire question and changing the language fom C to Java makes no sense, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

When you see there there is a LL node that has the same country, you are currently incrementing the count of the new node:

```
if(strcmp(curNode->data,bookings->country)==0){
        newNode->count++;
}
```

Instead what you can do is increment the count of the already existing node. Also in this case you'll not be inserting the new node, so you need to free the malloced node and return from the function:

```
if(strcmp(curNode->data,bookings->country)==0){
        curNode->count++;
        free newNode;
        return;
}
```

Comment: but i need to increment the count with this code when i add to my code the count is left to 1

Answer (score 0):

```
void insertitem(ListNode **startPtr,booking_type* bookings){
    int dif;
    ListNode *curNode. *newNode;


    for (dif = -1; (curNode= *startPtr); startPtr = &curNode->nextPtr ) {
      dif = strcmp(curNode->data,bookings->country);
      if (dif==0) {
          /* found it! we're almost done */
          curNode->count += 1;
          return; }
      if (dif > 0) break; 
    }
    /* when we get here, startPtr points to the pointer where we should
    ** insert our new node.
    ** *ptr becomes our tail, and ptr should point at the new node
    */
    newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
        /* TODO: check for malloc() failure here ... */
    strcpy(newNode->data, bookings->country);
    newNode->nextPtr = *startPtr;
    newNode->count = 1;  
    *startPtr=newNode;
    return;
}
```

Comment: *startPtr=newNode; is saying undefined

Comment: I reduced the code to (almost) the minimum. There is still a possibility for further reduction: you can remove the curNode variable... Maybe I made some typo's in the variable names, I am not that good at CamelCase.